# Probability flux

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, momentum, probability

I was reading a text on Quantum Mechanics in which it said that
$$\int{d^3 x \, j(x,t)} = \frac{\langle p\rangle}{m},$$
where $\langle p\rangle$ is the expectation value of the momentum operator at time $t$.
I tried using  $$\langle p\rangle = \int d^3x \, \psi^* (-i\hbar \nabla) \psi.$$

Either I am using the wrong $\langle p\rangle$ or carrying out the following steps wrong but I keep missing out the second term of $j$ given below:

$$j(x,t) = -(i\hbar /2m)[\psi^*\nabla\psi-(\nabla \psi^*)\psi]$$

Have I misunderstood meaning of $j$ or $\langle p \rangle$?

Comment: Hint: Integration by parts.

Answer (score 2):

I was stuck on this same problem. ACuriousMind does give a good hint though. Using integration by parts on the second term for $j(x,t):$

\begin{align*}
\int d^3x ~ j(x,t)&=-\frac{i\hbar}{2m}\int d^3x~ \left(\psi^* \nabla\psi-(\nabla\psi^*)\psi\right)\\
&=-\frac{i\hbar}{2m}\left(-\left[\psi^*\psi\right]^{+\infty}_{-\infty}+\int d^3x~(\psi^*\nabla\psi+\psi^*\nabla\psi)\right)\\
\end{align*}
The boundary term goes to zero and we get the result:
\begin{align*}
\int d^3x ~ j(x,t)&=-\frac{i\hbar}{2m}\int d^3 x ~ 2\psi^*\nabla\psi\\
&=\frac{1}{m}\int d^3 x~\psi^*(-i\hbar\nabla)\psi\\[3pt]
&=\frac{\left<p\right>}{m}
\end{align*}